# Can PHP read variables from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

Hi i'm begineer in PHP/JS and i have small question, how can PHP read values of variables in JavaScript?

i have this JS code where i have values

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function test(tag) 
{
var output = tag; 
<?php $tags ?> = output; //i tested, but not works
}
</script>
```

there's php read code

```
<?php
echo "$tags";
?>
```

i'm in end with this, Thanks for answers!

Comment: it won't , php will execute in web server and response will sends to browsers. you can use ajax functionality for this scienario

Comment: No, why you need it?

Comment: Outside of the function, try this: alert('<?php echo $tags; ?>'); and make sure it's outputting what it should.

Comment: @Naisapurushotham You can use PHP in JQuery if it's inline in the HTML rather than in its own file. Although, I wouldn't suggest people go this route. It's rather clunky and seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $tags ?> = output; //i tested, but not works
```

should be

```
<?php echo $tags ?> = output;
```